# Copy data from full node to a new pruned node to sync faster

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node

I already have a full node synced with `blocks` and `chainstate` folder, however i wanted to run a pruned node, is there a way to copy the blocks or chainstate folder to make the initial sync of the pruned node faster?

Comment: It will be same as copying any other directory. Copy blocks and chainstate. Start bitcoind with prune=N where N>550 (MiB)

Comment: Thank you @Prayank. When i start it as proned, will it remove all the other blocks data?

Comment: Yes it will remove if prune is saved in config.